# jQuery append the same form from previous form

Tags: jquery, button, onclick

Why is my append is not working when I click it.
I have example link of my website [Link](http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/index.php)

So for this website plugins, if you click the `Select` it will hide the selected playlist, after selecting that Playlist, you will see that at the buttom of the YT Player, meaning it was added to your playlist/database. so this is the append of my select.

**jQuery**:

```
$(function() {
    $(".videoThumbS").click(function() {    
        var dataString = $(this).siblings('input[name="v_w_id"]').val();
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',                                  
            url: 'api.php',
            data: { v_w_id: dataString },
            dataType: 'html',               
            success: function(data) {
                var viewrecord = dataString;
                $('.selected_thumbs').append('<a class="videoThumb4" href="" id="previewbutPL"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+viewrecord+'/default.jpg" /></a><input type="hidden" name="vid_delete" value="'+viewrecord+'" />');
                $("."+viewrecord).hide();
                $('input[name=delete]').click(function(){
                    $(".delVid").ajaxStop(function() {$("#"+deletedRecord).remove();});
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

place of the append playlist
`<div class="selected_thumbs"></div>`

and the button select

```
<?php
echo '
<a class="videoThumb4" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '" id="link">
' . $yValue['description'] . '
</a>
<input class="videoThumb4" type="button" name="previewSel" value="Preview" id="previewbut" />
<input id="v_w_id_value" type="hidden" name="v_w_id" value="' . $yValue['videoid'] . '" />
<input class="videoThumbS" type="button" name="selectSel" value="Select" id="selectbut" />

';
?>
```

My question here why is it not clickable when it was already append. Try to click the selected list you want. then Click the thumbnail of your playlist. You will notice it is not clickable. But when you use firebug the value was there and correct.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The select button is not "clickable" because you're script Jquery is

```
$(function() { ...
```

it means Document.ready.function

If you add a thumbnails with the click action after loading the pages the action `$(".videoThumbS").click(function()` will not be set on it.
You need to call the bind "mannually" on every new thumbmails

Comment: i guess you dont get what i mean. what i mean here for example i click select, so not there is a new added thumbnail, now this new added thumnail is no longer clickable why is that?